# Probability exponential RV belongs to interval $[n, n+1]$ with $n$ odd

Tags: probability, random-variables, exponential-distribution

Let $X$ be an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda > 0$. Calculate the probability that $X$ belongs to the interval $[n,n+1]$ with $n$ odd.

From the [solution](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041sc-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2013/unit-ii/lecture-9/MIT6_041SCF13_rec09_sol.pdf) (Q1) I see we need to sum over all odd $n$ but I'm confused as to why the answer doesn't depend on $n$? Surely as $n \rightarrow \infty $ the probability falls to $0$ and is different than for small $n$?

Any help on my misunderstanding appreciated.

Comment: The question is asking about any odd number, rather than a particular odd number.

Comment: Yes I know...but I'm still confused.

Comment: In this case, any odd number literally means that it can be **any** odd number. So the answer is a summation over **all** odd numbers. This sum contains all the arbitrarily small probabilities for large n that you alluded to.

Comment: Right, so we can actually show that for $n$ even the probability is $1/(1+e^{-\lambda})$ and the odd and even case summed together equal 1. Maybe the Q would be clearer if it said 'any' interval rather than 'the' interval. Thanks

Comment: Yes, absolutely, it should say "any" instead of "the". But it's not surprising that the problem is badly formulated, as the solution is bad, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you link to is way too complicated. I'm surprised that this is the solution suggested in an MIT course. It teaches you to perform a mechanical calculation instead of applying an idea.

The map $x\to x+1$ is a bijection from the non-negative reals with even integer part to those with odd integer part. The probability density at $x+1$ is $\mathrm e^{-\lambda}$ times the density at $x$. It follows that the integral of the density over the non-negative reals with odd integer part is $\mathrm e^{-\lambda}$ times the integral over those with even integer part. Thus, if we denote the probability to obtain an even integer part by $p_\text e$ and the probability to obtain an odd integer part by $p_\text o$, we have $p_\text o=\mathrm e^{-\lambda}p_\text e$. Since $p_\text o+p_\text e=1$, it follows that

\begin{eqnarray*}
p_\text e&=&\frac1{1+\mathrm e^{-\lambda}}\;,\\
p_\text o&=&\frac{\mathrm e^{-\lambda}}{1+\mathrm e^{-\lambda}}\;.\\
\end{eqnarray*}

(As clarified in the comments, there's no dependence on $n$ because the intended interpretation is “any interval” instead of “the interval”).

Comment: Thanks for this. How do we know that the pdf at $x+1$ is $e^{-\lambda}$ the density at $x$?

Comment: @maw501: Because the PDF is $f(x)=\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}$ and $f(x+1)=\mathrm e^{-\lambda(x+1)}=\mathrm e^{-\lambda}\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}$.